# Compute environments are not displayed in AWS console

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-batch

Compute environments created via boto3 are not displayed in AWS console. I can see them in the batch_client.describe_compute_environments() call response:

```
{
  'computeEnvironmentName': 'name',
  'computeEnvironmentArn': 'arn:aws:batch:us-east-1:<ID>:compute-environment/ml-retraining-compute-env-second',
  'ecsClusterArn': 'arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:<ID>:cluster/ml-retraining-compute-env-second_Batch_b18fcd09-8d7e-351b-bc0f-13ffa83a6b15',
  'type': 'MANAGED',
  'state': 'ENABLED',
  'status': 'INVALID',
  'statusReason': "CLIENT_ERROR - The security group 'sg-2436d85c' does not exist",
  'computeResources': {
    'type': 'EC2',
    'minvCpus': 0,
    'maxvCpus': 512,
    'desiredvCpus': 24,
    'instanceTypes': [
      'optimal'
    ],
    'subnets': [
      'subnet-fa22de86'
    ],
    'securityGroupIds': [
      'sg-2436d85c'
    ],
    'instanceRole': 'arn:aws:iam::<ID>:instance-profile/ecsInstanceRole',
    'tags': {
      'component': 'ukai-training-pipeline',
      'product': 'Cormorant',
      'jira_project_team': 'CORPRJ',
      'business_unit': 'Threat Systems Products',
      'created_by': 'ml-pipeline'
    }
  },
  'serviceRole': 'arn:aws:iam::<ID>:role/AWSBatchServiceRole'
}
```

but the Compute Environments table on the Batch page in AWS console UI does not show anything. The table is empty. When I try to create compute environment with the same name again via boto3 call, I get this response:

```
ERROR - Error setting compute environment: An error occurred
(ClientException) when calling   the CreateComputeEnvironment operation: Object already exists.
```

Comment: Maybe you have different region set in console?

Comment: Yes, absolutely right, @Marcin. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. I added an answer for future reference if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments, the issue was the use of **different region in the console**.

The solution was to change the region.